# Add titles to tabbar created programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I am new to iPhone development...  Now I am trying to build an application in which i am creating `UITabbarController` programmatically like below:

```
UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
firstViewController  *firstView = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *tabItemOne = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstView] autorelease];
secondViewController *secondView = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *tabItemTwo = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: settings] autorelease];
tabbar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItemOne, tabItemTwo,nil]; 
tabbar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);

[self.view insertSubview:tabbar.view belowSubview: firstView.view];
[self presentModalViewController:tabbar animated:NO];
```

In this, how can I add titles to `tabbar` and those controllers.
I have tried:

```
firstView.title = @"First View";
```

and

```
tabItemOne.title = @"First View";
```

But these two don't work.. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you inserting the subview below firstView's view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting **aViewController.title** sets the *title* for both the *navigationItem* and the *tabBarItem*. If you want the *navigationItem* and the *tabBarItem* to have different *title*, do this,

```
// First set the view controller's title
aViewController.title = @"First View Tab";

// Then set navigationItem's title
aViewController.navigationItem.title = @"First View";
```

Comment: Finally it worked.. I moved my code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear and it worked.. Thanks a Lot..

Answer (score 0):

```
UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First View" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"First View.png"] tag:0];
[tabItemOne setTabBarItem:item];
[item release];
```

If I'm correct.

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did it crash? The title didn't show? Did you set it to the controller you added to the array?

Comment: Here's the signature of the method, make sure it matches the one in your code `- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image tag:(NSInteger)tag;`

Comment: You don't have to set the view controller's tabBarItem property.  UIViewController lazy loads this property, creating a tabBarItem for you automatically the first time you access this property.  So you can simply do `controller.tabBarItem.title = @"Tab Title";`

Comment: There's no such thing as `tabBarItem.title`. Also, with that method you'll also be able to set an image.

Comment: Finally it worked.. I moved my code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear and it worked.. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

To set the label for your controller's tab, do this:

```
tabItemOne.tabBarItem.title = @"First View";
```

(By the way, you may want to reconsider your variable names.  They're pretty confusing.  tabbar sounds like it should be an instance of the UITabBar, when it's actually a UITabBarController.  firstView and secondView sound like instances of UIView when they're actually instances of a UIViewController subclass.  tabItemOne and tabItemTwo sound like instances of UITabBarItem, when they're actually instances of UINavigationController.)

Comment: It dint help.. Actually i modified namings to put code here.. In my code i named it related to our product only.. Anyway thanks..

Comment: Finally it worked.. I moved my code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear and it worked.. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITabBarItem *item= [[[[appDelegate tabBarController]tabBar]items ]objectAtIndex:0];
       //item.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hometab.png"];
       item.title=@"First View";

    item= [[[[appDelegate tabBarController]tabBar]items ]objectAtIndex:1];
       //item.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hometab.png"];
       item.title=@"Second View";
```

Comment: Finally it worked.. I moved my code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear and it worked.. Thanks a Lot.